# why does the pseudo-inverse blow up in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

Consider the following code. Why does the norm of `pinv` of `AA.T` blow up? Is there a more numerically stable way of computing it?

```
# Why does the norm of pinv(AA.T) blow up?

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# number of equations
nn = 225 

# norm of pinv of AA and AA.T
AA_pinv_norm  = []
AAT_pinv_norm = []

for nn in range(1,nn):
    AA = np.asarray([[0.1,0.1]]*nn)
    
    pinv_AA = np.linalg.pinv(AA)
    AA_pinv_norm.append(np.linalg.norm(pinv_AA))  
    
    pinv_AAT = np.linalg.pinv(AA.T)
    AAT_pinv_norm.append(np.linalg.norm(pinv_AAT))  
  
    
fig , ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1)
ax1.plot(AA_pinv_norm,'go-',markerfacecolor='none',label='norm(pinv(AA))')
ax1.plot(AAT_pinv_norm,'rx-',label='norm(pinv(AA.T))')
ax1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False,style='plain')    # to prevent scientific notation.
ax1.set_title('Blow up of norm(pinv(AA.T))')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xlabel('size')
ax1.set_ylabel('norm of pinv')
ax1.legend()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What happens

You are trying to compute a Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of a matrix whose rank is 1 and dimension way more than 1.

That is legal, sure. That is even what pseudo inverse are for.

But at some point, in the computation, that will involve many small values that should be exactly 0 but that numerically are not.

Let's do it by hand

```py
import numpy as np

AA=np.asarray([[0.1,0.1]]*100)

u,d,vh=np.linalg.svd(AA, full_matrices=False)

# d are the singular value
# And AA is (u*d)@vh
print((u*d)@vh)
```

Gives

```
# [[0.1, 0.1],
#  [0.1, 0.1],
#  ... (97 lines)
#  [0.1, 0.1]]
```

Pseudo inverse is then

```
InvAA = (vh.T*(1/d)) @ u.T
```

Well, almost so. Because `d` contains some "pseudo 0". So we should use pseudo inverse of `d`, to do this computation. Pseudo inverse of a diagonal matrix is easy: it is the matrix whose diagonal is made of the inverse of the non zero diagonal elements.

Here, d, is 1D, and just the values of the diagonal. So `invd` would be `[1/x for x in d if np.abs(x)>0]`

But, since, this is numerical computation, `0` is the ideal threshold. We need a more realistic one. Let's say `1e-15`

In our case, that threshold is just fine: we known the true rank is 1. And svd computation gives for `d`:
`d=[1.41421356e+00, 1.79973556e-16]`

(So it acted as if rank was 2, with a very small singular value)

```py
invd=[1/x for x in d if np.abs(x)>1e-15]
InvAA = (vh.T * invd) @ u.T
print(InvAA)
```

You can check that it works:
`InvAA@AA@InvAA` is `InvAA`
`AA@InvAA@AA` is `AA`
`AA@InvAA` and `InvAA@AA` are both symmetric

Let's do the same from `AA.T`

```py
u,d,vh=np.linalg.svd(AA.T, full_matrices=False)
invd=[1/x for x in d if np.abs(x)>1e-15]
InvAAT = (vh.T * invd) @ u.T
print(AA.T@InvAAT@AA.T)
```

This times, it doesn't work. And if we look at `InvAAT` values, what happens is obvious: very huge values. Note, that it almost works tho. `AA.T@InvAAT@AA.T` is not that far from being the same as `AA.T`, compared to the huge values that computation is made of.
So, it is obviously a numerical precision problem.

If we look at `d` we can immediately see why

`d` is `[1.41421356e+00, 1.95277784e-15]`

So, our `1e-16` threshold is not sufficient here.

What if we just lower it

```py
u,d,vh=np.linalg.svd(AA.T, full_matrices=False)
invd=[1/x for x in d if np.abs(x)>1e-14]
InvAAT = (vh.T * invd) @ u.T
print(AA.T@InvAAT@AA.T)
```

It works again!

Of course, with the risk of loosing information, if one of those cut "almost 0" singular values were not really 0. But in our case, no problem (any way, we know the real rank is 1. So we could in reality choose to just keep the fist value of `d` and discard the rest).

## Why it happens

Now, why this happens more with `AA.T` than with `AA`; why the numerical error is bigger with `AA.T` than with `AA`. I can't really say, since I don't know the specific of numpy's svd algorithm.

But if you look at many equivalent way to compute Moore-Penrose's pseudo inverse, or singular value decomposition, you'll see that it involves either computing eigen values of `M.T@M`. And `AA.T@AA` is a 2×2 matrix. When `AA.T.T@AA.T` is a nn×nn matrix. So, unsurprisinly, the latter involves more noise.

Another method is to compute limit of `(M.T@M+εI)⁻¹@M.T`. Which likewise, involves inverting a 2×2 matrix, with an almost rank 1, but one ε value, to make the rank to 2, in the case of `AA`. And a 100×100 (for nn=100 as in my example) matrix with an almost rank 1, but 99 ε values to make the rank 100, in the case of `AA.T`. Obviously, you will have a harder time make it converge, and numerical error when ε is really small will be bigger in the latter case than in the former.

You can play with this method

```py
np.linalg.inv(AA.T@AA + 1e-13*np.identity(2))@AA.T
```

Seems to give a reasonable value for the pseudo inverse. While

```py
np.linalg.inv(AA.T@AA + 1e-14*np.identity(2))@AA.T
```

is worse (so if you make ε smaller and smaller, the approximation is better and better till 1e-13, then it becomes worse and worse. For the usual reason: math says "the smaller the better", while numerical error says "the smaller the worse". Apparently, numerical error takes the leads around 1e-14.

If you do the same for `AA.T` case

```py
np.linalg.inv(AA.T@AA + ε*np.identity(2))@AA.T
```

This times it is around 1e-10 that numerical error starts to worsen the results.

So, with this also, you can see that it is harder, from a numerical point of view, to compute pseudo inverse of `AA.T` than to compute the pseudo inverse of `AA`

None of the two methods I've given are probably the one used by numpy. But same kind of consideration probably applies. Numerical error is just bigger in case of `AA.T`

## How to prevent it

So, long story short: what you must consider to be `0` when selecting singular values need to be bigger in second case.
And with `pinv` that is what `rcond` parameter is for.

Just add `rcond=1e-10` in your `pinv` call, and you get this

[image]

But of course, this comes with the usual tradeoff: a too big `rcond` risk ignoring significant (small but really not 0, not just numerical error) values. So you risk to end up with a pseudo inverse of a rank even smaller than the rank of your matrix. Of course, not in your case, since you matrix is rank 1. And but for the null matrix, there isn't any smaller rank any way. As I said, you could even just, with the svd method, drop all the d values but the first one: `(v.h/d[0])@u`. But that is only because you know that your matrix is really of rank 1 (and that numpy's svd sort singular value from the bigger to the lower)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. What threw me off was, that a matrix and it's transpose have the same singular values. So, I was surprised that it was working for A but not A^T. But of course, the singular values are not the same numerically, especially when close to zero.